# Safari using significant energy

Tags: safari, battery, power-management, safari-extensions

I am currently using a 2017 Mac Pro touch bar that is still on Mojave 10.14.6. My safari is consistently shown using significant energy on my menu. In my activity monitor, I noticed there are many apps running behind my safari despite only opening 4 tabs: mailbox, youtube, google and apple stack exchange. Is there any way to remove the apps shown running as shown in the screenshot and to prevent safari from using significant energy? [image: Screenshot for Safari activity monitor]

Comment: Are you using any extensions ?

Comment: The window is showing Avg Energy Impact over the past 12 hours. Current impact is almost nil, except for YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the high number is the **average** energy impact, not the **current**.
This is in line with what you say you currently have open: merely 4 tabs.

Since I don't know what you have been doing before, I can't tell you exactly what might have caused this energy impact. But there is quite some cached Safari web content ([Safari is using too much RAM. How can I reduce its memory footprint?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/safari-is-using-too-much-ram-how-can-i-reduce-its-memory-footprint), quite old though).

Probably the easiest way to **solve the issue** is to (force) quit Safari (Activity Monitor → Safari → *in the left upper corner* X → Quit/Force Quit) and restart your MacBook Pro.

If the problem persists try to delete web page cache with Safari → Preferences → Privacy → Advanced → Show Develop menu in menu bar, then in the menu bar at the top Develop -> Empty Caches.

You can also follow this guide, it also explains how to delete cookies:

- https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/clear-safari-cache-3496193/

Note: Flash Player is a notoriously bad extension (slow and unsecure). If you have it installed, remove it. You shouldn't need it these days. You can read more about it here:

- https://lifehacker.com/you-really-shouldnt-be-running-adobe-flash-player-anymo-1829721122